# Cursor Takes Several Minutes to Appear After Boot

Tags: display, gtk, cursor

Recently on Ubuntu 16.04 it takes several minutes before the cursor appears after my system has booted up and is otherwise responsive. I noticed that the Radiance GTK theme also takes several minutes to display and it kicks in at the same time the cursor appears. Whats going on?

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean the mouse pointer, right?  Does clicking or right-clicking the mouse have any effect before its pointer appears?

Comment: Yes, I mean the mouse pointer. Right-clicking has no effect. I can still see where the mouse is by the way the icons look when the cursor hovers over them, its just invisible.

Answer (score 2):

Once you're fully booted to your desktop, start a terminal (ctrl-alt-t) and type this command:

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

Put `sudo` in front of that command if you have any messages about permissions.

From [Ubuntu Manpage: systemd-analyze - Analyze system boot-up performance](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/systemd-analyze.1.html):

```
systemd-analyze blame prints a list of all running units, ordered by  
the time they took to initialize. This information may be used to  
optimize boot-up times. Note that the output might be misleading as the  
initialization of one service might be slow simply because it waits for  
the initialization of another service to complete.
```

This may help you track down what takes so long to load.

Comment: Thanks! I ran systemd-analyze blame. How can I post the results? As I don't know what to make of it.

Comment: `systemd-analyze blame` will show which (boot?) processes are taking the longest (longest running process showing first). You don't need to post the results just read them yourself and see which process(es) are taking the longest to complete. Depending on your needs you can determine for yourself which process(es) to disable. For example I once found bluetooth to be taking a long time to start-up and since I don't really use bluetooth I was able to disable that process using `sudo systemctl disable bluetooth`